# Reconstruction Conjecture and Partial 2-trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[Reconstruction conjecture](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/reconstruction_conjecture) says that graphs (with at least three vertices) are determined uniquely by their vertex deleted subgraphs. This conjecture is five decades old.

Searching relevant literature, I found that the following classes of graphs are known to be reconstructible :

- trees
- disconnected graphs, graphs whose complement is disconnected
- regular graphs
- Maximal Outerplanar Graphs
- maximal planar graphs
- outerplanar graphs
- Critical blocks
- Separable graphs without end vertices
- unicyclic graphs (graphs with one cycle)
- non-trivial cartesian product graphs
- squares of trees
- bidegreed graphs
- unit interval graphs
- threshold graphs
- nearly acyclic graphs (i.e., G-v is acyclic)
- cacti graphs
- graphs for which one of the vertex deleted graph is a forest.

I recently proved that a special case of partial 2-trees are reconstructible. I am wondering if partial 2-trees (a.k.a [series-parallel graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph)) are known to be reconstructible. Partial 2-trees do not seem to fall into any of the above mentioned categories.

- Am I missing any other known classes of reconstructible graphs in the above list ?
- In particular, are partial 2-trees known to be reconstructible ?

I asked this [question at cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/reconstruction-conjecture-and-partial-2-trees) website also.

Comment: This might be a good question to ask at mathoverflow, http://mathoverflow.net/ , with a [reference-request] tag in addition to the [graph-theory] tag.